# Spark-Submit execution time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have developed a Scala Program on Spark which connected MySQL Database to pull the data about 250K records and process it. When I execute the application from the IDE itself (IntelliJ) it takes about 1 min to complete the job where as if I submit through Spark-Sumit from my terminal it takes 4 minutes.

Scala Code

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().
      appName("credithistory").
      master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
```

From Terminal

```
spark-submit --master local[*] .....
```

Any changes should I have to make or it is normal behaviour? Since `local[*]` I have it in code also Im supplying from terminal.

Comment: I think you can try to compare the metrics available in the spark ui for both the jobs. And, prop up your question with them backing up your claim, if they don't make sense.

Comment: I would check spark ui and compare properties listed under the "environment" tab

Answer (score 0):

> local[K]  Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine).

it's from the reference of spark web page. [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

you can adjust the number of 'K',
for example, "local[4] or local[8]" following your CPU performance.